# Как передать повторяющиеся значения серверу?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Необходимо передать серверу значения таблицы в четыре столбца. количество строк заранее не известно все строки имеют разные id но внутри каждой стандартные name. Как всё это чудо лучше передать серверу?

```
            <tbody id="ntbody">
        <tr id="0">
            <td>Цвет<select name="color" id="">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>Размер<select name="size" id="">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1jgwbz</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>Артикул<input type="text" name="art"></td>
            <td>Количество<input type="text" name="count" style="width:50px;" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Из всего этого хотелось бы получить на сервере массивчег типа

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [color] => 1
        [size] => xl
        [art] => 123
        [count] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [color] => 1
        [size] => xl
        [art] => 123
        [count] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [color] => 1
        [size] => xl
        [art] => 123
        [count] => 10
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [color] => 1
        [size] => xl
        [art] => 123
        [count] => 10
    )

)
```

пробовал jquery:

```
$.ajax({url: 'echo.php', data:$('#ntbody select, #ntbody input', success: alert(html))});
```

В echo.php:

```
<?php print_r($_GET);?>
```

Но так принимается первая строчка((

Что посоветуете делать?

Comment: Решено если кому пригодится:
оставил старый js, php наменил на:

function crazy(){
 $uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $uri=explode("?",$uri);
 $uri=explode("&",$uri[1]);
 foreach($uri as $ur){
  $h=explode("=",$ur);
  $array[$h[0]][]=urldecode($h[1]);
 }
 return $array;
}
print_r(crazy());

Хотя отправить всё дело со странице в джсоне представлялось куда быстрее и удобнее, но не тут-то было...
Всем удачи.

Comment: Переделал проще
<pre>
function crazy(){
 $uri=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $uri=explode("&",$uri);
 foreach($uri as $ur){
  $h=explode("=",$ur);
  $array[$h[0]][]=urldecode($h[1]);
 }
 return $array;
}
</pre>

Comment: @jaggmanm все те данные, которые вы `explod`'ите, уже лежат в массиве $_GET (а должны - в $_POST).